# What do I need to do when the square symbol pops up during an enemy attack?

Tags: the-last-of-us

In the Last of Us, an enemy sometimes will pounce me and grapple.

A sort of quick-time event popups up with a square symbol bouncing around the screen; it *seems* to respond to my joystick movement to position itself on the screen, but I don't know if it's true.

What is this quick time event and how do I win the tussle? My game plan so far has been smashing square and wobbling the joystick but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 11):

Just smash on the square button like the dickens.